# Integrating CUDA into a C++ application to use existing C++ class

Tags: c++, cuda, fortran

I have an existing application that uses a C++ class, a C++ wrapper, and FORTRAN code for the computationally intensive parts of the application. I would like to implement parts of the FORTRAN in CUDA to take advantage of parallelization, but I would still like to access some of the subroutines, so I need to link CUDA, C++, and FORTRAN code.

I have three questions:
1. How do I correctly link all of the object files with the Linux Terminal and with the Makefile (included below)?
2. What is the proper way to reference the CUDA function in the class header without confusing the compiler's recognition of device and host code?
3. Is passing a class to CUDA just like passing a class to any other external C code?

Note: I have not included full code (some of it is quite long) except for the Makefile. If I need to include more, please let me know.

.h file

```
#ifndef _DGCPM_H_
#define _DGCPM_H_

extern "C"{

#include <string.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <math.h>

}

/* Prototypes of Fortran subroutines */
 extern "C" {
  void initialize_(float *2Darray);
  void advance_(float *2Darray);
  //Want "advance" to be implemented in CUDA
}

/* Proper prototype of CUDA call? */
//extern "C" void cudaadvance(float *2Darray);

class DGCPM{

public:
  DGCPM(); /* Initialized with defaults setup */
  ~DGCPM(); /* Free memory */

  void advance(float dT); /* Advance model dT seconds */

private:

  float **2Darray;
  void initialize(float **2Darray);

};

#endif
```

.C wrapper

```
#include "../include/DGCPM.h"

DGCPM::DGCPM(){

  initialize();
}


void DGCPM::advance(float dT){

  advance_(2Darray[0]);
}
```

main.C file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <zlib.h>

#include "../include/DGCPM.h"

int main(){

  class DGCPM *model;
  model=new class DGCPM();

//Write data to class from a file, then

  for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
    printf("%d\n",i);
    model->advance(3600);
    //write model state to file;
  }

 //Close file

  return 0;
}
```

Makefile (Note: "pbo" is the FORTRAN code)

```
INSTALLDIR=../../lib/

FLAGS=-Wall -g -I ../../amj/include
CFLAGS=$(FLAGS)
CPPFLAGS=$(FLAGS)
FFLAGS=$(FLAGS)

CPP=g++
CC=gcc
FC=g77

PBO_PATH=../ober/for/
VPATH=$(PBO_PATH)

DGCPM_OBJ=DGCPM.o pbo.o
TESTDGCPM_OBJ=testDGCPM.o DGCPM.o pbo.o

ALL_OBJ=$(TESTDGCPM_OBJ)

install: all
    mkdir -p $(INSTALLDIR)
    cp libDGCPM.a $(INSTALLDIR)

all: libDGCPM.a testDGCPM

libDGCPM.a: $(DGCPM_OBJ)
    ar rc $@ $^

testDGCPM: $(TESTDGCPM_OBJ)
    $(CPP) -o $@ $^ -L ../../amj/lib -lamjMemory -lg2c -lz

clean: 
    - rm $(ALL_OBJ)
    - rm $(INSTALLDIR)/libDGCPM.a
```

Comment: Concerning your third question, I had a legacy code written in C++ and using classes. I have managed to port the code to `CUDA` by just changing all the CPU operations (executions, memory movements, etc.) to GPU operations (kernels, `cudaMemcpy`s etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. To use the CUDA code, I reference it with, for example,

```
extern "C" void myfunction_(void)
```

In the header file, I add

```
void myfunction_(void);
```

in the extern "C" prototypes. In the public functions of the class I added

```
void mycudafunction(void);
```

In the C++ wrapper, I add

```
void DGCPM::mycudafunction(){
 myfunction_();
}
```

I can now call "myfunction" from the main program with this type of syntax

```
model = new class DGCPM();
model->mycudafunction();
```

I modified my Makefile by adding myfunction.o to all of my objects and adding

```
-L /usr/local/cuda/lib -lcuda -lcudart
```

to all of my linking instructions.

To compile, create the CUDA object file (myfunction.o), and link, I type this in the terminal:

```
nvcc -c myfunction.cu
make
```

Here is the modified code:

.h file

```
#ifndef _DGCPM_H_
#define _DGCPM_H_

extern "C"{

#include <string.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <math.h>

}

/* Prototypes of Fortran subroutines */
 extern "C" {
  void initialize_(float *2Darray);
  void advance_(float *2Darray);
  /*CUDA prototype, can be changed to "cudaadvance" or the like*/
  void myfunction_(void);

}

class DGCPM{

public:
  DGCPM(); /* Initialized with defaults setup */
  ~DGCPM(); /* Free memory */

  void advance(float dT); /* Advance model dT seconds */
  void mycudafunction(void); 
private:

  float **2Darray;
  void initialize(float **2Darray);

};

#endif
```

.C Wrapper

```
#include "../include/DGCPM.h"

DGCPM::DGCPM(){

  initialize();
}


void DGCPM::advance(float dT){

  advance_(2Darray[0]);
}

void DGCPM::mycudafunction(){
  myfunction_();
}
```

main.C file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <zlib.h>

#include "../include/DGCPM.h"

int main(){

  class DGCPM *model;
  model=new class DGCPM();

//Write data to class from a file, then

  for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
    printf("%d\n",i);
    model->mycudafunction();
    model->advance(3600);
    //write model state to file;
  }

 //Close file

  return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
INSTALLDIR=../../lib/

FLAGS=-Wall -g -I ../../amj/include
CFLAGS=$(FLAGS)
CPPFLAGS=$(FLAGS)
FFLAGS=$(FLAGS)

CPP=g++
CC=gcc
FC=g77

PBO_PATH=../ober/for/
VPATH=$(PBO_PATH)

DGCPM_OBJ=DGCPM.o pbo.o myfunction.o
TESTDGCPM_OBJ=testDGCPM.o DGCPM.o pbo.o myfunction.o

ALL_OBJ=$(TESTDGCPM_OBJ)

install: all
    mkdir -p $(INSTALLDIR)
    cp libDGCPM.a $(INSTALLDIR)

all: libDGCPM.a testDGCPM

libDGCPM.a: $(DGCPM_OBJ)
    ar rc $@ $^

testDGCPM: $(TESTDGCPM_OBJ)
    $(CPP) -o $@ $^ -L ../../amj/lib -lamjMemory -lg2c -lz -L /usr/local/cuda/lib -lcuda -lcudart

clean: 
    - rm $(ALL_OBJ)
    - rm $(INSTALLDIR)/libDGCPM.a
```

Here's the simple CUDA program I used to test.

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel( void ) {

}

extern "C" void myfunction_(void) {

    kernel<<<1,1>>>();
    printf( "Hello, World!\n" );
    return;


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You currently don't have any CUDA code, so I may can't give enough details.

For your Qs:

1. Linking object files including CUDA code requires [nvcc compiler driver](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html). You could first compile your code files with individual compilers, i.e. `gcc` for `.c`, `g++` for `.cpp`, `g77` for `.f` and `nvcc` for `.cu`. Then you can use `nvcc` to link all the object files `.o`;
2. host and device code are explicitly declared in .cu file with `__host__` and `__device__`. It's your responsibility not to invoke device code from other host code;
3. Why are your passing a class to CUDA? If you want to replace your fortran code with CUDA, you only need to invoke CUDA functions in your C++ wrapper class, and invoking CUDA API functions uses the the same grammar as invoking c++ functions.

Here is an example from my project. The executable is built with 1 `.cu`, 1 `.cpp`, a few extern `.a` as well as some `.so`. For `.cpp` I use Intel's compiler `icpc` other than the default `g++`. Please note my `main()` is in the `.cu` file.

```
# Compile   : bin.cu/b-rbm-gpu.cu
nvcc -ftz true -ccbin icpc -Xcompiler "-Wall -Wno-long-long -ansi -pedantic -ansi-alias -parallel -fopenmp -openmp-link=static -static-intel -wd10237" -O3 -Xcompiler "-O3"   -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20  -Ilib -c -o bin.cu/b-rbm-gpu.o bin.cu/b-rbm-gpu.cu
# Compile   : lib/KTiming.cpp
icpc -Wall -Wno-long-long -ansi -pedantic -ansi-alias -parallel -fopenmp -openmp-link=static -static-intel -wd10237 -O3  -MMD -Ilib -c -o lib/KTiming.o lib/KTiming.cpp
# Link  : bin.cu/b-rbm-gpu
nvcc -ftz true -ccbin icpc -Xcompiler "-Wall -Wno-long-long -ansi -pedantic -ansi-alias -parallel -fopenmp -openmp-link=static -static-intel -wd10237" -O3 -Xcompiler "-O3"  -Ilib -Llib bin.cu/b-rbm-gpu.o lib/KTiming.o -lpthread -lm /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -lcublas -lcurand -lcusparse -o bin.cu/b-rbm-gpu
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Eric. It helped me arrive at a solution. I have included the documentation for my solution in my own answer.